# iptables port forwding - nothing returned

Tags: linux, iptables, portforwarding

I'm stumped.

This is how my iptables are configured on Debian 7.

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 127.0.0.1/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.1.130.5/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
```

Basically forwarding port 80 to port 8090.

I also have an instance of Apache Tomcat running and listening on port 8090. e.g.

```
sudo lsof -i :8090
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    15081 user1   36u  IPv6 164737      0t0  TCP *:8090 (LISTEN)
```

However, whenever I try to connect via a browser nothing get returned. Its the same using Wget. e.g.

```
wget www.test.com/confluence
--2016-04-22 16:59:22--  http://www.test.com/confluence
Resolving www.test.com... 10.1.130.5
Connecting to www.test.com|10.1.130.5|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /bootstrap/selectsetupstep.action [following]
--2016-04-22 16:59:22--  http://se-    www.test.com/bootstrap/selectsetupstep.action
Reusing existing connection to www.test.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Comment: probably better asked on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your ruleset that actually forwards ports.  You have `INPUT` rules, which will accept or reject packets destined for the local host, and you have `FORWARD` rules, which will accept or reject rules transiting the machine to another address, but you don't have anything that actually changes the target port of a connection.

If you actually want to change some aspect of a connection, this falls into the broad category of "network address translation" (NAT), which is carried out in the `nat` table, rather than the default `filter` table.

Possibly you need `REDIRECT` rule in your `nat` table:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 \
  -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8090
```

Note that a `REDIRECT` rule will only operate on traffic that *does not originate on the local host*.  You will need to test this from another host on the network (or from inside a container or a vm).

Alternatively, you could accomplish something similar using proxy software such as [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).

Some additional reading:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/179200/difference-beetween-dnat-and-redirect-in-iptables
- https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection